# Timeout in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, timeout, mpmovieplayercontroller

At low speed, the video played by MPMoviePlayerController keeps loading. No timeout or any other error is shown. Is it possible to set a default timeout for this player?

Is there a generic function which can be used for all the players?

Comment: You don't mention what iOS version you're supporting but be aware that `MPMoviePlayerController` was deprecated in iOS 9.0 SDK. (https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpmovieplayercontroller?language=objc) You should move to the newer AVPlayerViewController.

Comment: Hey, you are right. We are migrating to JWPlayer but in the meantime we want to support MPMoviePlayerController.